# Should I quit my new part-time job for a full time position else where.

Tags: resignation, fulltime, part-time

I got hired part-time a store a few days ago and my first day was yesterday. Today i got a call about a position i applied for a few weeks ago which is full time with way better pay. I'm 18 and this is my first job I've ever had. will leaving right away impact me future? should I? how to i explain it to my boss?

Comment: Only you know your situation, options and priorities. We can't make up your mind for you.

Comment: Part time jobs are there to get you through until a full time job come along or you are studying. Leaving one after a few days is something your boss will be used too.

Answer (score 4):

No, quitting a part-time job to accept a full-time offer will not impact your future. Just be honest with your boss, and let him/her know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Let your current boss know that you are taking off for the full-time position. Say something nice to them on the way out.

Do NOT write anything in your resume that you worked there for a few days. You don't include a few days work on your resume unless you were literally saving the world during that time interval.